# Strange NullPointerException from conditional operator

Tags: java, oop, nullpointerexception, null

When I execute the following code, `NullPointerException` occurs:

```
public static Integer getProperty(String name, Integer defaultValue) {
    String value = null;
    try {
        return (value != null) ? Integer.parseInt(value) : defaultValue;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    getProperty("unit", null);
}
```

Can somebody explain me why this is happening?

Comment: first NullPointer are clearly defined. 2nd which line? any stacktrace? Normaly should be closed because [what´s a nullpointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I look's like you are always having null in value, you are never initializing it to a value

Comment: See the duplicate question for the answer. In order to fix your snippet, you can use `Integer.valueOf(value)` instead.

Comment: Apparently it tries to auto-unbox the defaultValue as the left side of the ternary operator is `int`. Then it would auto-box it to return an `Integer`. If you do as Alexis said, you'll have `Integer` on both, thus no unboxing happens.

Comment: @AlexisC., thank you very much!

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you are using an IDE like Eclipse you can turn on 'INFO' on autoboxing/unboxing, it will underline you places in code where it happens, avoiding such questions in the future.

Comment: A NullPointerException happening while unboxing is pretty hideous, with no apparent de-referencing happening in the code. I remember it confusing multiple coworkers in the past, and me as well. Now you know, and you won't be so surprised next time :)